# Complicated (my)SQL left join

Tags: mysql, join, null, left-join

Is it possible to have a left join which would give a result like in the following assumption:

TABLE A:

```
id   value
1    foo
2    bar
3    foobar
```

TABLE B:

```
foreign   foreign_value
1         fish
1         soup
```

The result of the join should be every result of table A (left join) and additionally the  joined results beetween A and B:

SELECT * FROM A complicated join B ON A.id=B.foreign:

```
id   value    foreign   foreign_value
1    foo      NULL      NULL
1    foo      1         fish
1    foo      1         soup
2    bar      NULL      NULL
3    foobar   NULL      NULL
```

When doing a normal LEFT JOIN the first row of the shown example-resultset would not exist.

Is such a select possible?

Comment: What you mean is `outer join`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. This is not a join at all since it includes non existent values from elsewhere. (null-null for foreign/value in case of id=1 for example). Knowing more about it would help.

Comment: The whole story is probably about a bad database/table design which resulted from adding an additional feature. In a CMS we show "News" records which are assigned some page (simple int field "pid"). The new feature allows News to be shown on more than one page. For this I added an M-M table containing news<-->page relations. Now I have to combine the old "pid" type query with the new MM query and the whole thing boils down to this question.

Comment: If I want to count the number of news on a page I will have to count those news which really reside on the page + additionally those news which get referenced from within the MM-table

Comment: I solved the problem from within PHP by executing two separate queries. I was just curious if it would be possible from within a single query - for which a join similar to the above example would have to exist. But thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

No, such a join is not possible, because you will not get the first line.

You could use a union like

```
SELECT a.id, a.value, b.foreign, b.foreign_value 
FROM A inner join B ON A.id=B.foreign
    UNION
SELECT a.id, a.value, null, null
FROM A
```

This will give the expected result in your example, but I don't understand why you try to do this. Therefore I don't know if this gives the expected result in the general case.